# Update vs Refresh in ORMLite

Tags: dao, crud, updates, ormlite

`Dao<T,ID>` Interface provides many DAO methods such as update,create ,...etc

I [read](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#update(T)) that Update method

> will not save changes made to foreign objects or to foreign
>   collections.

Did refresh method save changes made to foreign objects or to foreign collections?
Generally, what's the main difference between `update` and `refresh` methods?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Did refresh method save changes made to foreign objects or to foreign collections?

No.

> Generally, what's the main difference between update and refresh methods?

The `update(...)` method writes changes you've made to an object in memory into the database.  I'll quote from the [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) Javadocs.  [`update(...)` is](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#update%28T%29):

> Store the fields from an object to the database. If you have made changes to an object, this is how you persist those changes to the database. You cannot use this method to update the id field -- see updateId(T, ID) .

The `refresh()` method on the other hand, updates your object in memory from the database. Here are the [`refresh(...)` javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#refresh%28T%29):

> Does a query for the object's id and copies in each of the field values from the database to refresh the data parameter. Any local object changes to persisted fields will be overwritten. If the database has been updated this brings your local object up to date.

When the docs say that the `update(...)` method won't save changes to other objects, it's because those objects are maintained in different tables.  If you have an `Account` with a collection of orders, calling update on the `account` only updates those fields.  If you made a change to one of the orders then you are going to have to use the `OrderDao` to update the order in the order table.